# Printf variable number of decimals in float

Tags: c, printf

I found interesting format for printing nonterminated fixed length strings like this:

```
char newstr[40] = {0};
sprintf(newstr,"%.*s",  sizeof(mystr), mystr);
```

So I think maybe is there a way under printf command for printing a float number...

> "%8.2f"

to have ability to choose number of decimals with integer number.

Something like this:

```
sprintf(mystr, "%d %f", numberofdecimals, floatnumbervalue)
```

Comment: REMOVED: 
EDIT - Solution:  
(for rounding and clearing a float number to desired precision).
```c
    int precision = 2;  
    char kolf[16] = {0};  
    sprintf(kolf, "%8.*f", precision, mystruct.myfloat);  
    float kol = atof(kolf);  
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can also use `".*"` with floating points, see also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ (refers to C++, but the format specifiers are similar)

> **.number**: For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be
>   printed after the decimal point (by default, this is 6).
>
> ...
>
> **.***:   The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an
>   additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to
>   be formatted.

For example:

```
float floatnumbervalue = 42.3456;
int numberofdecimals = 2;
printf("%.*f", numberofdecimals, floatnumbervalue);
```

Output:

```
42.35
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use the asterisk for that too, both for the field width and the precision:

```
printf("%*.*f\n", myFieldWidth, myPrecision, myFloatValue);
```

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Thanks Joach, this is what I search for.

Comment: +1 for the link to the "C" part of `en.cppreference.com` - bookmarked :)

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, your actual C library doesn't support variable precision and width for float formatting, it's not too hard to build the format string your own:

```c
char fmt[6 + 3*(sizeof width + sizeof precision)]; /* sufficient space */
sprintf(fmt, "%%%d.%df\n", width, precision);
printf(fmt, value);
```

Of course this comes at a cost, but - depending on your situation - this can be maybe centralized.