# Calculate number of numbers in float C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that calculate the width or how many numbers a float contains. I need this to make good looking outputs in console. For example, the width of the following numbers are:

```
4     (1)

23    (2)

0.3   (3 because the . has the width of one)

0.45  (4)

12.34 (5)

0     (1)
```

I have tried to check if the `number == 0` then the width is `1` and done, and else multiply the number with `10` until there is no decimals `float == (int)float` and then calculating how many times it is needed to divide by `10` to get a number `float < 0.` I have tried everything I have found at the internet without any real luck...

Comment: "Print" to a string and get the length of the string?

Comment: print to a string and count its length. or check the printf format specifiers that can do this for you.

Comment: Floats are not exact. So the 0.3 could also be represented as 0.2999999999999 and counting the number of digits would not be very helpful.

Comment: `printf` format specifiers are how you do this. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413609/printf-variable-number-of-decimals-in-float). If you want fixed number of decimal places every time you can hardcode a number rather than use the `*`

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using the formatting already available to you: `printf()` [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?  You should be able to round, set minimum field widths, etc.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 1):

Just use snprintf for counting length of what you want to print, like this:

```
int main()
{
    float num;
    int len;
    if (1 == scanf("%f", &num)) {
        len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%g", num);
        printf("%g (%d)\n", num, len);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just got DV for the same solution - no explanations given. I hope you will have better luck! Do not  forget about `'.'` and `'-'` sign.

Comment: @sg7 Your solution is complicated, maybe that's why you have got a DV. P.S. I didn't forget about anything!

Comment: @freestyle I misread the requirement. My bad. I corrected my program and compared our solutions.

Comment: @sg7 Yes, it can make sense, but why is buffer size 32? I think print to buffer is overhead for this task. If I understand correctly, author of question want to calculate max width of numbers for pretty alignment them into column, like `for (...) maxWidth = max(maxWidth, snprintf(NULL, 0, cellFormat, ...));`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert float to the string. 
You may use `snprintf` or something  similar for your needs.

The precision of the conversion of the `snprintf` may not be best. 
You may want to limit number of characters after the `'.'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float num = -12345.678; 
    char str[32];
    size_t counter = 0;

    // freestyle solution
    int len;
    printf("Please input the number:\n");
    if (1 == scanf("%f", &num)) {
        len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%g", num);
        printf("\%g (%d)\n", num, len);
    }

    //sg7: improved one - '.' and '-' counted.
    len = snprintf(str, 32, "%f", num);
    printf("\n%s Number of characters: %zu",str, len);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Please input the number:                                                                                                                       
-12.345678                                                                                                                                     
-12.3457 (8)                                                                                                                                   

-12.345678 Number of characters: 10
```

Comment: Solution improved `'.'` and `'-'` are counted.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your float is stored in the variable `f`, you can do this:

```
int width; char buffer[50];
width = sprintf(buffer,"%f",f);
```

Please keep in mind that floats are usually stored with a precision of six digits after the decimal point, so a number like 14.2 is stored as 14.200000 thus having a width of 9 instead of 4. It might be stored as 13.999999 as well so keep that in mind.