# Print float with actual float size

Tags: c

Im trying to print out a format of lets say x levels of accuracy meaning it should print if x = 10

```
float foo;
printf("levels of accuracy %.10f", foo);
```

What i've tried:
I already have the math to convert the x to the desired decimal place.
something like..

```
int multiplier = 10;
float initialaccuracy = 1.0;
float threshold = initialaccuracy / ((float)(pow(multiplier, accuracy)));
```

What I want to know:

How do i use the format of that x into the printf so if i pick x= 4 it would be %.4f or if i pick 15 it would be %.15f, without hardcoding those values just using it of whatever i pass in?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413609/printf-variable-number-of-decimals-in-float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `*` in place of the precision specifier and pass it as a separate parameter:

```
int accuracy = 10;
printf("levels of accuracy %.*f", accuracy, foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, build your format string 'on the fly'...

```
char fmt[99];
sprintf(fmt,"levels of accuracy %%.%df",accuracy);
printf(fmt,foo);
```

Comment: The first seemed a bit easier to understand but I appreciate the response. Ima look into sprintf haven’t used it yet.