# is there a way to use a variable to print a number to different decimal places in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am new to coding in C, and I was wondering if it is possible to print a float, ex: float l = 2.718281;
such that the program prints:
2
2.7
2.71
2.718
2.7182
2.71828
2.718281

I know how to do this using simple printf statements, but how would I go about doing this in a for loop? This is the code I have, where I am trying to replace the number of decimal places with i, then print the statement, but it is not working

```
int main()
{
    float l = 2.718281;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%.if\n", l);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413609/printf-variable-number-of-decimals-in-float

Comment: `printf("%.*f\n", i, l);`